# What resources mean in ACL in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, resources, acl

I want to know what is resouces in ACL, is it module, controller in a module or action in controller in module.

In the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.refining.html), resoiurces (newsletter, news,latest) and others are not clear what they are.

Also in this [example](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFUSER/Using+Zend_Acl+with+a+database+backend#UsingZend_Aclwithadatabasebackend-DatabaseInitialisation%3a) the resources are not clear!!!

```
[mainMenu]
login          = Everyone
applications   = Everyone
preferences    = User
administration = Implementor

[userPreferences]
details = User
params  = User
themes  = User
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource is simply something you want to limit access to. It could be a page, a record in your DB or whatever your application needs.

I wrote a three-part series on Zend_Acl, in which I talk about what resources are amongst other things: http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/

Comment: How the ACL objects in Zend framework distinguish between files, actions, controllers and other resources?? If I want to store resources in the db,how the application will understand different types of resources.

Comment: I've addressed that as well in the articles. However, to shortly explain it, you could simply use a prefix in your resource name. For example, `file-foobar` or `action-helloworld`

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
new Zend_Acl_Resource('someResource')
```

Denotes that `someResource` points to an PHP module/section, which is suppose to be accessible but, it has be controlled so that only authorized roles can access it.

Comment: please check the comment in Jani Hartikainen answer.

Comment: @PalAla, Actually it does not, you have query the ACL, with given action, controller, and modules, which points to an actual resource name, which at last get authorized against the roles.

Comment: Then I have to store it the database the exact module, controller and action for each resource, right?

Comment: @PalAla, If you are using database based ACL then yes

Comment: Both answers are right but I mark Jani Hartikainen answers's cz the article is very useful.

Comment: @PalAla, Sure no problem, glad I could add up.